# how to develop a desktop application that follow instagram users and unfollow them

Tags: instagram, desktop-application

Followliker or instagram bot can follow users, unfollow users, upload photos, like photos, unlike photos, comment on photos. And it is a desktop application. 
I want to develope my own instagram bot but i don't have any idea how it works, does anybody know how it was made?

Comment: from here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 1):

As of Oct 1, 2017, Instagram is no longer giving permission other than basic, which means you cannot do like, follow comment using API anymore :(

More info here:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

> Starting 10/1/2017, all permissions other than the basic permission
>   will be unavailable to submit for or obtain.